# Receive php multidimensional array in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, html-framework-7

I have this php

```
include_once($preUrl . "openDatabase.php");

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM dish';
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$nRows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($nRows > 0){
    $dishes = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dishes[] = $row;
    }
}else{
    $dishes = "cyke";
}


   echo json_encode($dishes , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

and this ajax (in framework7)

```
myApp.onPageInit('dailyMenu',function() {
    $$.post('http://theIP/eatsServer/dailyMenu.php', {}, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
    });
});
```

What i get in the ajax data is

{"0":{"idC":"2","title":"helloWorld1","subtitle":"hellsubWorld","price":"16.5","img":"img/testeImg.jpg","soldout":"0"},"1":{"idC":"3","title":"helloworld2","subtitle":"hellosubWorld2","price":"20.5","img":"img/testeImg.jpg","soldout":"1"}}

I already tried data.[0]; data.['0']; data.0; data0 when i use data["0"] just gives me the '{'.

I want to acess the title and the rest inside that 0. to do a cicle for where i will print multiple divs where i only change the array position in a html page.

Exemple

```
for(...){

   innerhtml += <div clas="">

                  <div class""> data(position i).title </div>

                  <div> data(position i) subtitle</div>

                </div>

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one (after callback add type: json)

```
$$.post('url', {}, function (data) { 
  var obj = JSON.parse(data); 
  console.log(obj); 
  alert(obj["1"].title); 
});
```

or maybe you can use JSON.parse(data);

Comment: i tried already but whenever i put ex:var 
 obj=jQuery.parseJSON(json_data); but the alert or the consoleLog will not work

Comment: use: var obj = JSON.parse(data);

so:
$$.post('http://theIP/eatsServer/dailyMenu.php', {}, function (data) {
           var obj = JSON.parse(data);
           console.log(obj);
    }, 'json');

Comment: I putted what u said in the commentatys but that isnt in the answer so do i mark you anwser as correct or what?here if u need to edit what i putted     $$.post('url', {}, function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(obj);
            alert(obj["1"].title);
    }); NOTE: Thanks it work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are receiving a json data  as response, you should use this:

```
$$.post('http://theIP/eatsServer/dailyMenu.php', {}, function (data) {
        console.dir(data);
},'json');
```

Pay attention to `},'json');`on end of the code, now the $$.post is reading the response as a JSON.

If you aren't doing any update to data base, you could use:

```
$$.getJSON('http://theIP/eatsServer/dailyMenu.php',{}, function (data) {
  console.dir(data);
});
```

This is the way with $$.ajax:

```
    $$.ajax({ 
        url: "url_here",
        method: "POST",
        dataType:"json",        
        data: {},
        success: function(r){   
          // response r.
        }, error: function(error){
          //error
        }
    });
```